# How can I create a concrete version of an abstract data type for Stream purposes?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, reduction, abstract-data-type

This code displays what I want to do (but does not work).

```
abstract class Item<I extends Item<I>> {

    public abstract void add();
    public abstract void test();

    public static <T extends Item<T>> Item<T> getZero() {
        return T.ZERO();
    }

    protected static <T extends Item<T>> Item<T> ZERO() {
        class ZERO extends Item<T> {
            public void add() {}
            public void test() { System.out.println("item"); } // don't call this
        }
        return new ZERO();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item.<Book>getZero().test();
    }
}

class Book extends Item<Book> {

    public void add() { /* addition implementation goes here */ }
    public void test() { System.out.println("book"); } // this should be called

    protected static Item<Book> ZERO() { return new Book(); }

}
```

I want to make sure that when `Item.<Book>getZero()`, it calls `Book.ZERO()` instead of `Item.ZERO()`. However, due to type erasure, this does not work, and the program prints `item`.

I want to modify this to make this work (preferably avoiding the use of reflection). Here is the purpose of this:

If I call `Arrays.stream(books).collect(Item.<Book>getZero(), Item::add, Item::add);`, I want to be able to add all of the items.

To facilitate computation (and avoid dealing with `Optional<Book>`), I want to define a concrete ZERO object. However, since I intend all implementations of `Item` to be mutable, I want to make sure that each subclass of `Item` (such as book) has its own mutable implementation. **In other words, the default implementation of ZERO is a placeholder for operations and should not be used.**

I want to do this without passing extra objects to the calling methods (addition / zero methods should be inherent in each implementation of `Item`) and without requiring an instance of an `Item` object to create a ZERO object. This is useful to me because I want to perform operations with `Item`s knowing only that they can be added and compared, which allows me to save the implementation of `Item` for later.

Comment: Why are your generics self-referential?

Comment: Why can't you just use `Book.ZERO()` instead of `Item.<Book>getZero()`

Comment: I took this idea from the way BaseStream is defined in Java 8. Also, I want to make sure that I can call Item<Book> book = new Book(); since Item<T> objects are what I intend to work with.

Comment: @Codebender's approach is pretty much as good as it's going to get.  You can't do what you're trying to do in Java, in the sense that you can't have anything like overridable static methods.

Comment: @Codebender The class from which the stream is called has type parameter <T extends Item<T>>, and I intend to use Item.<T> definitions for this reason. However, if this doesn't help anything, I can switch.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Would T.ZERO() be acceptable in this context, where T is a type parameter of the class that computes the stream?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Since I'm calling it from a class ItemGroup<T extends Item<T>> and T is generic, I can't use T.ZERO() from that class. (This is because I want to keep the implementation open for such objects.)

Comment: @Natecat I want to use Item<Book> book = new Book();

Comment: @Codebender In this case, Book is a generic type.

Comment: @aspaltv, no, you cannot do T.ZERO() or anything like it. You cannot call a static method on a type variable.  In the best case it will work but it will always call Item.ZERO() and not actually reflect the type variable you have there.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Alright, what are my options then with respect to this problem?

Comment: It looks like you're badly overgenerifying the problem.  Try solving it for a concrete type without trying to make your solution generic.

Comment: @LouisWasserman What I want to be able to do is to make the class used in Item interchangeable (could be number, vector, matrix, data structure, etc.)

Comment: @aspaltv what you're trying to do isn't really doable in Java.  There's not really a way to do that.

Comment: The closest thing you could do is have concrete objects of a type like `Operator<T>` that knows how to add, subtract, and generate zeroes for another type.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the items you want to collect have the same type (this cannot be checked statically), you can make the instance method (not static method) returning zero and defer the container creation until the first element is collected. Something like this:

```
abstract class Item<I extends Item<I>> {

    public abstract void add(I another);
    public abstract void test();

    // Instance method: returns new ZERO-container of the same type like this object
    // Actually could be abstract
    public I getZero() {
        class ZERO extends Item<I> {
            @Override
            public void add(I another) {}
            @Override
            public void test() { System.out.println("item"); } // don't call this
        }
        return (I) new ZERO();
    }

    // Creates collector which aggregates any specific type of items
    public static <T extends Item<T>> Collector<T, ?, T> collector() {
        class Container {
            T acc;
        }
        return Collector.of(Container::new, (cont, t) -> {
            // accumulator is initialized only on first addition
            // so we can use the first element to request the ZERO of the same type
            if(cont.acc == null) cont.acc = t.getZero();
            cont.acc.add(t);
        }, (c1, c2) -> {
            if(c1.acc == null) return c2;
            if(c2.acc != null) c1.acc.add(c2.acc);
            return c1;
        }, cont -> cont.acc); // unpack in finisher (returns null for empty stream)
    }
}
```

Now we can redefine methods in subclasses:

```
class Book extends Item<Book> {
    public void add(Book another) { System.out.println("Book added"); }
    public void test() { System.out.println("book"); }
    public Book getZero() { return new Book(); }
}

class Food extends Item<Food> {
    public void add(Food another) { System.out.println("Food added"); }
    public void test() { System.out.println("food"); }
    public Food getZero() { return new Food(); }
}
```

And you can use the same collector regardless of the actual types of collected objects:

```
Book books = Stream.of(new Book(), new Book()).collect(Item.collector());
Food foods = Stream.of(new Food(), new Food()).collect(Item.collector());
```

Note that for empty input stream you will have `null` returned as you have no objects to mimic `ZERO` from. If this is unacceptable, then the only solution I could propose is to pass around `Class<? extends Item>` object and create the corresponding `ZERO` using reflection (like `clazz.getMethod("getZero").invoke(null)` assuming `getZero` is static).

Comment: How do I handle the case when there is nothing in the Stream (I still want to return a ZERO object)

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to be able to write

```
Arrays.stream(books).collect(Item.<Book>getZero(), Item::add, Item::add);
```

you seem to be unaware that due to type erasure, the method `Item.getZero()` has no knowledge about the type parameter `<Book>` you have specified. The behavior of a method does not change due to its parametrization. In fact, you can even write `Item.<Book>getZero()` when the `Item.getZero()` method is not generic at all.

But what’s even more important, your desire to have code that is independent of the actual type is not fulfilled at all. In the term `Item.<Book>getZero()` there is a reference to the type `Book` which has to be adapted when the stream element type is a different subtype of `Item`. So why not specify `Book::ZERO` (or just `Book::new`) in the first place?

```
abstract class Item<I extends Item<I>> {
    public abstract void add(I other);
    public abstract void test();
}

class Book extends Item<Book> {
    public void add(Book b) { /* addition implementation goes here */ }
    public void test() { System.out.println("book"); } // this should be called
    public static Book ZERO() { return new Book(); }
}
```

Usable as

```
Book b = Arrays.stream(books).collect(Book::ZERO, Item::add, Item::add);
```

so before complicating the design, you should think about what you actually can gain from the change.

Note that the `Supplier` needed as first argument to `collect` is exactly the abstraction of a method that returns a specific object (like the zero instance) that you are looking for. When extracting the supplier from the `collect` operation, you can abstract the operation, e.g. when you add the following method to the `Item` class

```
static <T extends Item<T>> Collector<T,T,T> sum(Supplier<T> getZero) {
    return Collector.of(getZero, Item::add, (a,b)->{ a.add(b); return a; });
}
```

you can use it like

```
Book b = Arrays.stream(books).collect(Item.sum(Book::ZERO));
```

Comment: In this case, Book itself is a type parameter of the class that calls Stream.collect(). As such, Book::ZERO might not work. I am considering doing a workaround as in the other answer, but I know it looks a bit hackish, so I'm interested in other options that allow me to defer the creation of subclasses of Item to the end of development.

Comment: It is not required that the immediate caller uses `Book::ZERO`; the caller might pass through the factory `Supplier` instead. In either case, there is an initiator somewhere knowing the actual type and that initiator can provide the `Supplier`.

Comment: In this case, Book is a type variable for another class, and as someone told me earlier, I cannot call a lambda method reference on a type variable.

Comment: I can find a way to do this (by passing such an object to the method), but it looks pretty sketchy, and I want to see if I can hide this object.